# Get values from rows based on col Name from a range?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get the values from rows based on the col name from a range.
Hard to explain in words, will show example to illustrate.

From Col A to Col L: Jan-2018, Feb-2018, March-2018 ...... goes on (basically mths of the year)
There's rows of data under each column.

How can I get the row's data for current month?

I can't even get myself started because I cnt think of a way/function.
Only manage to get the date value.

```
Dim getDate As String

getDate = Format(Now(), "mmm-yy")
```

Tried to look into `Application.VlookUp` but does not seem like it as I'm not looking for a single value.

[image]

Comment: Are your date headers actual dates, or text?  You can (assuming the latter) use `Find()` or `Application.Match()` to locate the header, then use that to locates the values.  Or (if your months start at Jan and you only have a single year) use the month number.

Comment: @TimWilliams Hi, they're custom formatted to  "mmm-yy", should be date.

Comment: In VBA, you probably want to do something with `Columns(Month(Now()))` or, if processing row by row, `Cells(r, Month(Now()))`.  If using Excel formula, you might want to use something like `=OFFSET(A1,0,MONTH(TODAY())-1)`.

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks for the suggestion. Excel Formula might not be the solution I'm looking at. Will be connecting  to outlook in later stage. I'm trying to look into the `Find()` as what Tim Williams suggested.

Comment: If you try Find then use the actual date, not the string from `Format()`, or it won't match.

Comment: @TimWilliams I believe I did the opposite?! I found the error (Not matching) and formated my cells from date to Sting. After i found out that it does not search dates.

Comment: That also works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solved the issue with @Tim Williams 's suggestion by using `Find()` and `mid()`.

```
Dim sendDate As String
sendDate = Format(Now(), "mmm-yy")

Dim rgFound As Range
'Need to format them to string due to Format(Now(), "mmm-yy")
Set rgFound = Range("F17:V17").Find(sendDate)
'get the Col name rgFound.Address return $K$17
colName = Mid(rgFound.Address, 2, 1) 'K
```

Then I used `For i = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` to loop the rows and assign the value to the array like this `data(cnt) = .Cells(i, colName).Value`.

Cheers :)